How to resolve kafka discnnection issue?
I am using Kafka Spring in my java Project and I have around 6 consumers .
I was having an issue that the kafka queue was filling up thus I created partitions or the topics equal to the number of consumers which is 6.
But then after making these changes I am still having issue that issue below:
So what could be the problem from the kafka server or my code?
 Requesting disconnect from last known coordinator kafka-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
2024-04-25T05:48:15.983Z  INFO 1 --- [istener-4-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-ms-payment-6, groupId=ms-payment] Requesting disconnect from last known coordinator kafka-service.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)

